# How to show the file name to the user that fopen created in PHP?

Tags: php, fopen

I am using

```
$fp = fopen(rand(1,10000000000).'', "w");
```

that creates files with user's Submitted content through a textarea. Once submited, I want to show the url of the file that is just created by the user. As the filename is random, I couldn't find any way to show the filename to the user.

Comment: `"http://example.com/uploads/" . $randomName`?

Comment: Are you sure to pollute your filesystem with that? I would prefer storing that in a database.

Answer (score 0):

A key skill in programming is breaking a problem down into smaller parts, allowing you to understand those parts, and reuse them in different ways.

Although this is a very simple line of code, it's doing two different things:

1. Generating a random filename
2. Opening a file handle

Quite simply, you need to make those into two separate lines of code:

```
$filename = rand(1,10000000000).'';
$fp = fopen($filename, "w");
```

Now you have a variable with the filename, which you can pass to whatever is doing the display to the user.

---

As an aside, if the purpose of the `.''` is just to make the value into a string, it would be clearer to use [the appropriate type casting operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php#language.types.typecasting): `(string) rand(1,10000000000)`.

Answer (score 0):

In its simplest form:

```
$filename = rand(1,10000000000).''; // Create filename and save in a variable
$fp= fopen($filename, 'w');         // Open the filen
echo $filename;                     // Tell the user.
```